# EF update statement with select query and where cause combined

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

```
UPDATE [Revision] 
SET [Value] = [Value] + 1
WHERE [Type] = 0 
  AND [Number] IN (SELECT [Number] FROM [User] 
                   WHERE Id IN (5111, 5211, 5311))
```

How to write this query in EF Core?

I tried with:

```
var n = await db.Users
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => id.Contains(x.Id))
                .Select(y => y.Number)
                .ToListAsync(s.Token)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

await db.Revisions
        .AsNoTracking() 
        .Where(y => y.Type == Consts.TABLE_USER && n.Contains(y.Number))
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(z => 
                   z.SetProperty(o => o.Value, o => o.Value + 1),
                   s.Token
                 ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

but it is not good performance as two round-trip.

I want to write EF Core only one round-trip for high performance.

Comment: Just remove first `ToListAsync`, anyway query can be rewritten if you show model classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to write this query in EF Core?

Don't fetch the users.  Just compose that into the update query using [Bulk Update and Bulk Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) eg:

```
//n should be a subquery expression, not a collection
var n = db.Users
          .Where(x => id.Contains(x.Id))
          .Select(y => y.Number);

await db.Revisions
        .Where(y => y.Type == Consts.TABLE_USER && n.Contains(y.Number))
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(z => 
                   z.SetProperty(o => o.Value, o => o.Value + 1),
                   s.Token
                 );
```